# Prove by contradiction the set $\mathbb{Z} $ is unbounded above and below?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi guys just a quick question.

How do I prove by contradiction the set $\mathbb{Z} $ is unbounded above and below???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the universe here is $\Bbb R$. In such a case, suppose there exists an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $n\leq x$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$. Consider $\lfloor x\rfloor +1\in\Bbb Z$. Can you find a contradiction?

The case where $x\leq n$ for each $n\in \Bbb Z$ is analogous, and I leave it to you to figure it out.

**NOTE** For a given real number $x$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ returns the greatest integer $n$ such that $n\leq x$. That it, it returns the "closest" integer to $x$ to the left. So, for example, $\lfloor 170625.06254\rfloor =170625$, while $\lfloor -3.2\rfloor =-4$.

Comment: my apologies but I'm not into this abstract kind of maths, it makes no sense to me so I have no idea how to even prove the question.

Comment: @RickyRozay: Did you _read_ Peter's answer, or did you just arbitrarily decide without even trying that you wouldn't be able to understand it?

Comment: @RickyRozay Let's make it concrete. Suppose $134095.4565$ was an upper bound for the integers. Then $\lfloor 134095.4565\rfloor+1=134095+1=134096$ is greater than this alleged upper bound, and is an integer.

Comment: @RickyRozay Make an effort, please. Make a drawing, try examples.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff is it: then $n-1\leq x$ which contradict x is the lower bound??

Comment: @RickyRozay If $x$ is a real number which is a lower bound, then $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer. There is no need to subtract one, but it also works. That is, $\lfloor x\rfloor -1 \in\Bbb Z$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor-1\leq x$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff ok