# Prove that the set $\mathbb{Z}$ is unbounded above in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My topology lesson casually made this assumption but I think it needs proof.

There is another thread with basically [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351242/prove-by-contradiction-the-set-mathbbz-is-unbounded-above-and-below) here on this stackexchange but I'm not satisfied with the accepted answer. It makes use of the $⌊x⌋$ function but doesn't prove that it's defined for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do you define "unbounded" and "bounded"?

Comment: Floor is usually defined using supremum of a set bounded above. Pretty well defined.

Comment: Answers to this question would depend on what OP knows about real numbers.

Comment: @Jack What I mean with $\Bbb{Z}$ being unbounded above in $ \Bbb{R} $ is that there exists no $x ∈ \Bbb{R}$ such that there exists no $n ∈ \Bbb{Z} \ge x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real numbers have the property that a subset which is upper bounded has a supremum.

Suppose $s=\sup\mathbb{Z}$. By definition of supremum, there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x\ge s-\frac{1}{2}$.

Can you arrive to a contradiction?

Hint: $x+1\in\mathbb{Z}$.